# c# how to list all files from ftp directory and read each file without downloading

Tags: c#, ftp

There is this for listing files from ftp directory:

```
FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
ftpRequest.Credentials =new NetworkCredential("username","pword");
ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());


string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
{
    // if file is .txt, read file content
}
```

But how do I read the content of the file? Not just the listing here?

(I would prefer now having to download them first)
Thanks.

Comment: if you want the contents, you have to download it

Comment: Are you open to using other FTP libraries?  If so I can provide an answer. - To read the contents you must download.

Comment: @confusedandamused, I'm open to using other FTP libraries...

Comment: Why other library? Actually did you notice the listing code is basically the same as downloading to memory? You also reading the listing from a stream to memory. Read the file contents the same way!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I was going to suggest WinSCP, but I'll let you answer from this point then :P

Comment: Thanks all, I've figured out a way to resolve this from your suggestions